# How to pass arrays through JSON php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'd like to pass arrays through JSON like this:

```
<?php

for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
  $arrayA[i] = "A" . i;
  $arrayB[i] = "B" . i;
}

echo json_encode($arrayA,$arrayB);

?>
```

I know it's not possible, but is there other way to pass dynamicly loaded arrays and read them in javascript after that?

Comment: what about this echo json_encode(array($arrayA,$arrayB));

Comment: @AdamWaite: That's JavaScript, he's asking for a PHP solution ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put both array in another array.

```
$returnArr = array($arrayA,$arrayB);
echo json_encode($returnArr);
```

On JS side just decode with a library of your choice and access the returned array like any normal array.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo json_encode(array('arrayA' => $arrayA, 'arrayB' => $arrayA));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create wrapper for your arrays:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    $arrayA[i] = "A" . i;
    $arrayB[i] = "B" . i;
}
$arrayC = array($arrayA,$arrayB);
echo json_encode($arrayC);
```

On jQuery side:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/yourPhpFile.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        // each `val` is one of the arrays you passed from php
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to load up a script that will return a PHP generated array. If you're using jQuery, you call it using either $.get() or $.getJSON(). You can read up on PHP JSON manual here http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php and on jQuery .getJson() function here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/